# Animate a sequence of UIButtons by moving from right to its original position

Tags: iphone, animation, uibutton

I don't have any idea of animation what so ever,I have used quite a few animations suggested,but nothing got working according to my requirement.I have a sequence of UIButtons displayed according to a word length,i.e. each button contains a character of that word.So what I want to do is while placing the word itself,I want the buttons to come from right and get back to their mentioned positions(co-ordinates).Here is how I create buttons equal to word length.

```
-(void)buttonsCreation:(int)noOfButtons
{
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            if (view.tag >=100)
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *charactersArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.wordButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:30];

    BOOL record = NO;
    int randomNumber;

    for (int i=0; [charactersArray count] < jumbledWord.length; i++) //Loop for generate different random values
    {
        randomNumber = arc4random() % jumbledWord.length;//generating random number
        if(i==0)
        {
            [charactersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j=0; j<= [charactersArray count]-1; j++)
            {
                if (randomNumber ==[[charactersArray objectAtIndex:j] intValue])
                    record = YES;
            }
            if (record == YES)
                record = NO;
            else
                [charactersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
        }
    }

    int arrayValue;
    float x = 60.0;
    float y = 50.0;
    for(int i=0;i<[jumbledWord length];i++)
    {
        if(i>=0 && i<10)
        {
            arrayValue = [[charactersArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            x = x + 37;
            UIButton *characterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            characterButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,175.0, 35.0, 35.0);

            [wordButtons addObject:characterButton];
            NSString *characterValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[jumbledWord characterAtIndex:arrayValue]];
            [characterButton setTitle:characterValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [characterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if (arrayValue==0)
            {
                arrayValue = 100;
            }
            [characterButton setTag:arrayValue*100];
            [self.view addSubview:characterButton];
        }
        else if(i>=10 && i<20)
        {
            arrayValue = [[charactersArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            y = y + 37;
            UIButton *characterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            characterButton.frame = CGRectMake(y,200.0, 35.0, 35.0);

            [wordButtons addObject:characterButton];
            NSString *characterValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[jumbledWord characterAtIndex:arrayValue]];
            [characterButton setTitle:characterValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [characterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if (arrayValue==0)
            {
                arrayValue = 100;
            }
            [characterButton setTag:arrayValue*100];
            [self.view addSubview:characterButton];
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S**-**Off post**: I am using the below code to dismiss the sequence of buttons from the view and then bring the next sequence of buttons i.e. next word

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if (view.tag >=100)
        {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.30f];
            view.transform =
            CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                                             view.frame.origin.x,
                                             480.0f + (view.frame.size.height/2)  // move the whole view offscreen
                                             );
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please guide me,thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *wordButtons;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *jumbledWord;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.jumbledWord = @"NORBERT";
    [self buttonsCreation:7];
    [self animation];
}

-(void)buttonsCreation:(int)noOfButtons
{
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            if (view.tag >=100)
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *charactersArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.wordButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:30];

    BOOL record = NO;
    int randomNumber;

    for (int i=0; [charactersArray count] < self.jumbledWord.length; i++) //Loop for generate different random values
    {
        randomNumber = arc4random() % self.jumbledWord.length;//generating random number
        if(i==0)
        {
            [charactersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j=0; j<= [charactersArray count]-1; j++)
            {
                if (randomNumber ==[[charactersArray objectAtIndex:j] intValue])
                    record = YES;
            }
            if (record == YES)
                record = NO;
            else
                [charactersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
        }
    }

    int arrayValue;
    float x = 60.0;
    float y = 50.0;
    for(int i=0;i<[self.jumbledWord length];i++)
    {
        if(i>=0 && i<10)
        {
            arrayValue = [[charactersArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            x = x + 37;
            UIButton *characterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            characterButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,175.0, 35.0, 35.0);

            [self.wordButtons addObject:characterButton];
            NSString *characterValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[self.jumbledWord characterAtIndex:arrayValue]];
            [characterButton setTitle:characterValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [characterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if (arrayValue==0)
            {
                arrayValue = 100;
            }
            [characterButton setTag:i+1];
            [self.view addSubview:characterButton];
        }
        else if(i>=10 && i<20)
        {
            arrayValue = [[charactersArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            y = y + 37;
            UIButton *characterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            characterButton.frame = CGRectMake(y,200.0, 35.0, 35.0);

            [self.wordButtons addObject:characterButton];
            NSString *characterValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[self.jumbledWord characterAtIndex:arrayValue]];
            [characterButton setTitle:characterValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [characterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if (arrayValue==0)
            {
                arrayValue = 100;
            }
            [characterButton setTag:i+1];
            [self.view addSubview:characterButton];
        }
    }
}

- (void)animation
{
    for(int i=0;i<[self.jumbledWord length];i++)
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i+1];

        CGFloat translation = self.view.frame.size.width - button.frame.size.width ;
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translation, 0);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:i
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Yeah everything is fine,but the words are coming from right a bit slow,how can I make it a bit fast,especially it has become slow when I click new word :)

Comment: updated the code. change the animation duration. it has been changed from 2.0f to 0.5f

Comment: I already tried reducing the animateWithDuration time to 0.5 seconds,what happens is buttons are rushing for the first word,but still the other button is waiting,I don't want the button to wait for other,more over from next time when new word is selected,what's happening is it is taking all the time in the world to arrive from right to occupy its original position,please help me out on this :)

Comment: I tried assigning 0 in delay,but what's happening is all words are arriving at a time,but I want one uibutton to follow after other and not wait till its successor button is occupying its place,just the policy of relay running event

Comment: Typical requirement Mr.Nobert,I am trying to remove the sequence of buttons from the view and animate the upcoming sequence of character buttons of a word when user opts for new word.What's happening is,your animation code snippet works fine,but 2-3 buttons are visible for medium length words in the view before its arrival and 4-5 buttons are visible for lengthy words.It is looking a bit odd since I am dismissing the existing buttons,i.e. I want a feel which is something like,sequence of buttons coming from background,i.e. out of view bounds and settle at their respective positions,thanks :)

Comment: Awaiting your response,I am unable to find ways,I even tried assigning translation depending on word length,so could you please help me out,how to bring the buttons from right from behind the screens,thanks :)

Comment: I have done some changes to your answer as I have found a solution to my requirement,please do approve it as I have also tested it on my project and it works fine,thanks :)

Comment: Another requirement,how to animate the sequence in form of changing the position of buttons when user opts for shuffling

Comment: @Mr.iCoder Please help me out,I am unable to find out a solution,thanks :)

Comment: You can shuffle the buttons by changing one buttons frame with the other and vice verse. Did u try it out?

Comment: I got the idea,but I don't know the approach,the buttons are created based on conditions and the number of buttons vary,so how do I calculate the x position and interchange the button positions among themselves,please give some sample code

Comment: have u used gitHub? can u provide me the access for your code. I can try. https://github.com/

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me some sample code instead of me storing the project in git and providing you the link,please understand.After the sequence of buttons appear,we need to shuffle or interchange their positions.It's not that we are creating the buttons once again using our transition animation

Comment: for (UIButton *characterButton in wordButtons)
    {
        id sortObject0 = [self.wordButtons objectAtIndex:0];
        id sortObject1 = [self.wordButtons objectAtIndex:1];
        id sortObject2 = [self.wordButtons objectAtIndex:2];
        [self.wordButtons removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self.wordButtons removeObjectAtIndex:1];
        [self.wordButtons insertObject:sortObject0 atIndex:1];
        [self.wordButtons insertObject:sortObject1 atIndex:0];
        [self.wordButtons removeObjectAtIndex:2];
        [self.wordButtons insertObject:sortObject2 atIndex:1];
    }
not working

Comment: `- (void)exchangeButton:(UIButton *)firstButton withAnother:(UIButton *)secondButton
{
    CGRect firstButtonFrame = firstButton.frame;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        firstButton.frame = secondButton.frame;
        secondButton.frame = firstButtonFrame;
    }];
}`

Comment: i have not tested the above method. Test that out. what i meant was exchanging the frames of the buttons like the above code. a simple method where u can pass two button and its responsibility is exchange the frame of each other with animation.

Comment: But how about first button and second button,it doesn't work because we are not assigning any value for those buttons.I mean wordButtons array contain the sequence of character button in the view and it is only one button in multiple forms i.e. containing all characters of a word as titles.

Comment: i am confused. Give me your requirements in the form of images so that i can create a sample app for u and upload it in github.

Comment: Please once check with the code above for understanding how I implement creating sequence of buttons in my question.There we are declaring "UIButton *characterButton" and duplicating with different titles using for loop.Hence I am little confused of using exchange with another button method :)

Comment: I am sorry I got your patience testing.We are creating a sequence of buttons using jumbled word length.We declare only one button and keep on adding them in the view till it reaches the word length.So your solution seems a little confusing,exchange button with another button.What I need to do there??

Comment: Please reply me,I tried this way: for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:2];
            [view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:2 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
            [view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:3 withSubviewAtIndex:0];
            [view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:3];
        }
    }
it didn't work

Comment: Try this `for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        [view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:2];
        [view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:3 withSubviewAtIndex:0];
    }
}`

Comment: `for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        [self exchangeButton:view.subviews[1] withAnother:view.subviews[2]];
        [self exchangeButton:view.subviews[3] withAnother:view.subviews[0]];
    }
}


- (void)exchangeButton:(UIButton *)firstButton withAnother:(UIButton *)secondButton
{
    CGRect firstButtonFrame = firstButton.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        firstButton.frame = secondButton.frame;
        secondButton.frame = firstButtonFrame;
    }];
}`

Comment: It is crashing: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: Instead when I assign self.view.subviews[22] instead of view.subViews[5] or something else.I am able to view motion of one button coming to other and finally no interchange takes place :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34040/discussion-between-eshwar-chaitanya-and-icoder)